# The Tenacious Thai Calendar

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes, date

In the [Thai calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_calendar) the year 2017 corresponds to 2560. The Thai calendar is always 543 years ahead of the Gregorian calendar.

Observant coders will note that 2560 is equal to \$2^9 \times 5\$, in other words it has 10 prime factors. This will not happen again for another 896 years! We call a year **tenacious** if it has exactly ten prime factors.

Write a program which outputs a truthy value if the current year using the Thai calendar, based on the system clock, is tenacious, and a falsey value otherwise.

Test cases:

- If the program is run during 2017, `true`
- If the program is run during any of the years 2018 to 2912, `false`
- If the program is run during 2913, `true` (\$2913+543 = 2^7 \times 3^3\$)

Comment: If using a language or running in an environment without a system clock, is it acceptable to take the current time as input?

Answer (score 6):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 35 bytes

```bash
factor $[`date +%Y`+543]|awk NF==11
```

Output is either a non-empty string (truthy) or an empty string (falsy).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S03OyFfIyy//n5aYXJJfpKASnZCSWJKqoK0amaBtamIcW5NYnq3g52Zra2j4Pw2oACybmaegnpdaUaJQmZpYpK5gZGBipGtgCEQKRpaGxhCmtUJKPhdnKsh8FfWYPHWVapBWVVVdrVouTjTbdFMUlFRALCWsFnOl5Oel/gcA)

#### Alternate version: 37 bytes.

```bash
date -d 543year +%Y|factor|awk NF==11
```

Not as golfy, but I like this one.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@SWJKqoJuiYGpiXJmaWKSgrRpZk5aYXJJfVJNYnq3g52Zra2j4/z8A)

#### How it works

The arithmetic expansion

```bash
$[`date +%Y`+543]
```

executes `date +%Y` to get the current (full) year and adds **543** to the year.

Factor takes the sum as an argument and prints it prime factorization: first the number to be factored, then a list of individual prime factors.

Finally, awk filters the input, printing only lines with exactly 11 fields (the number plus 10 prime factors).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55960/discussion-between-seshoumara-and-dennis).

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
žg543+ÒgTQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390X7qpibH24UnpIYH//wMA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymr/G9qYqx9eFJ6SOD/SqXD@60UDu9X0vlvZGBoxgUkzEGEBZeRpaERiDAGESYA)

**Explanation**

```
      Òg     # the number of primefactors with duplicates of
žg           # the current year
  543+       # plus 543
        TQ   # equals 10
```

Answer (score 4):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 13 bytes

```
et0=543+mf,A=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@59aYmBramKsnZum42j7/z8A)

#### Explanation

```
et0=  e# Get current year.
543+  e# Add 543.
mf    e# Get prime factors with multiplicity.
,     e# Get length.
A=    e# Equals 10?
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>37</s> 31 bytes

<sup>*5 bytes saved due to [lanlock4](/users/66104).*</sup>

```
PrimeOmega[#&@@Date[]+543]==10&
```

Anonymous function. Takes no input and returns `True` or `False` as output.

Comment: `Now` is implicit. You can use `DateValue@"Year"`.

Comment: Do you need the `&` at the end? Also, `Date[][[1]]` is a couple of bytes shorter than `DateValue@"Year"` (if you don't mind that `Date` is obsolete).

Comment: You can save a byte with `#&@@Date[]` in place of `Date[][[1]]`. Also, I think "Mathematica + REPL environment" is a valid programming language here, for which you don't need the terminating `&`.

Comment: @GregMartin Oh well, I've never been a big fan of that

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
qlP+543.d3T
```

[Online interpreter available here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qlP%2B543.d3T&debug=0)

### Explanation

```
       .d3   get current year
   +543      add 543
  P          get prime factors of result
 l           count number of prime factors
q         T  check if equal to 10 (result is implicitly printed)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>18 14</strike> 13 bytes

```
543+Ki¹k l ¥A
```

Saved 4 bytes thanks to ETHproductions.
Saved 1 byte thanks to obarakon.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@29qYqztnXloZ7ZCjsKhpY7//wMA)

Comment: Nice answer! You can save a byte if you move things around: `A¥º543+Ki¹k l` or `543+Ki¹k l ¥A`

Comment: @obarakon Thanks! Why is `¹` used, wouldn't `)` do the same thing?

Comment: Yep, you can use `)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>92</s> 89 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan</sup>

```python
import time
y=time.gmtime()[0]+543
c=i=1
exec"i+=1\nwhile 1>y%i:y/=i;c-=1\n"*y
print-9==c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@ZW5BfVKJQkpmbylVpC6L00nNBlIZmtEGstqmJMVeyrYF1pq0hV2pFarJSpratYUxeeUZmTqqCoV2laqZVpb5tpnUyWFhJq5KroCgzr0TB0MDWNvn/fwA)
Iterate up to the year, extracting (and couting) the prime factors.
The exec line is equivalent to :

```python
for i in range(2,y):
 while not(y%i):
  y=y/i
  c=c-1
```

Comment: A 3 byte save: `c=i=1`; `c-=1`; `print-9==c`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 31 bytes

```matlab
nnz(factor(clock()(1)+543))==10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@5@XV6WRlphckl@kkZyTn5ytoalhqKltamKsqWlra2jw/z8A)

Two tricks used here:

- `clock()(1)` to index directly into the output of `clock` (`clock(1)` doesn't work)
- `nnz` instead of `numel`, as all entries are guaranteed to be nonzero.

---

#### Alternate version, same byte count

```matlab
nnz(factor(max(clock)+543))==10
```

This version can only be used for years exceeding `30`, but <s>obviously</s> disregarding time travel this includes all years in which the program can be executed. It works in Matlab as well.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>111</strike> <strike>68</strike> 66

```
$a=date(Y)+543;for($i=2;$i<$a;)$b+=$a%$i?!++$i:!!$a/=$i;echo$b==9;
```

directly counts the number of prime factors.

```
$a=date(Y)+543;             // current year
for($i=2;$i<$a;)            // while $i lower than the year
$b+=$a%$i?!++$i:!!$a/=$i;   // if $i divides $a: $a/=$i and ++$b | if not: ++$i
echo$b==9;                  // output if it has 10 prime factors
```

---

### Old idea: <strike>111</strike> 90

```
for($i=1;++$i<1e3;)for($j=1;++$j<1e3;)${$i*$j}=($$i?:1)+($$j?:1);echo${date('Y')+543}==10;
```

This doesn't use a prime factortoring builtin but basically a *counting prime sieve* to get the number of prime factors of a number < 10000. This maps to the 4 digit year that PHP provides using `date('Y')`:

```
for($i=1;++$i<1e3;)          // for each number smaller sqrt(1e4)
for($j=1;++$j<1e3;)          // do sqrt(1e4) times
${$i*$j}=($$i?:1)+($$j?:1);  // n_factors[i*j] = n_factors[i] + n_factors[j]
echo${date('Y')+543}==10;          // output 1 if the current year has 10 prime factors or nothing if it doesn't
```

Comment: -2 bytes: `Y` needs no quotes with `-nr`.

Comment: On Your old idea: why initialize? `$a[$i*$j]=($a[$i]?:1)+($a[$j]?:1)` saves 13 bytes. `$j=++$i<1e4` saves one. And no quotes for `Y` two more.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
1&Z'543+Yfn10=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@2@oFqVuamKsHZmWZ2hg@/8/AA)

```
1&Z'   % Current year
543+   % Add 543
Yf     % Prime factor decomposition
n      % Number of elements
10=    % Equal to 10? Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 123 bytes

```
@set/ay=%date:~-4%+543,n=d=2
:l
@set/ar=y%%d,d+=1
@if %r%==0 set/ay/=d-=1,n+=1
@if %y% gtr 1 goto l
@if %n%==12 echo 1
```

You can fake out the script by manually overriding the `date` variable before running it.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>79</s> 75 bytes

```
f=(y=+Date().slice(11,15)+543,d=2,n=10)=>y>1?y%d?f(y,d+1,n):f(y/d,d,n-1):!n
```

Port of my Batch answer. Pass in the **Thai** calendar year if you want to perform a specific test. Edit: Saved 4 bytes thanks to @dandavis.

Comment: how about `new Date().getYear()+2443`

Comment: @Matt Ugh, that's not what MDN says it does... but it's deprecated, so I'm not sure I should be using it anyway.

Comment: _passing_ 2017 == `false`?  shortners: `+Date().slice(11,15)+543` and `y?` instead of `y>1`

Comment: @dandavis `y?` is pointless, `y` is never zero.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

Program body:

```
10=#q:543+{.6!:0''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@///v6GBrXKhlamJsXa1npmilYG6OgA)

`10=` is ten equal to

`#` the tally of

`q:` the prime factors of

`543+` this number added to

`{.` the head (first item, i.e. the year) of

`6!:0''` the date (as Y M D h m s)